# Ktor JSON Parsing on Post Request is not working

Tags: kotlin, ktor

Every time I send a post request from the postman and the server gives this error, even I checked if I'm receiving `Content-Type = Application/ JSON`. But still giving this error.

**Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.limit(I)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;**

**Here are my files**

> Application File:

```
fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "192.168.0.109") {
        install(ContentNegotiation){
            json()
        }
        configureRouting()
    }.start(wait = true)
}
```

> Request:

```
post("/login") {

    val userInfo = call.receive<UserInfo>()
    println(userInfo)

    call.respondText("Everything is working fine")
}
```

> Model Class:

```
@Serializable
data class UserInfo(
    val email: String,
    val password: String
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**So I Solved This Issue by Changing Project SDK 1.8 to 11.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`ktor_version:1.6.7` has fixed this problem.